# How to add thumb images to TRzGroup Item Menus

Tags: delphi

I am creating sidebar images with the help of TRzGroup. I already have created TRzGroup with caption Print Now and added item named Print to it. I am planning to add a small printer icon image at the left hand side of the menu item as shown in figure at bottom. How it can be done ?

```
object RzGroup2: TRzGroup
      Items = <
        item
          Caption = 'Print'
          ImageIndex = 4
          OnClick = RzGroup2Items0Click
        end>
      Opened = True
      OpenedHeight = 47
      DividerVisible = False
      SmallImages = ImageList1
      Special = True
      Caption = 'Print Now'
      ParentColor = False
    end
```

While this code is extracted from somewhere in the code SmallImage attribute is assigned to ImageList1. I assume it is for image menu. I checked at object inspector there is SmallImages property but not sure how to create ImageList1 and assign to SmallImages.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop a `TImageList` from the Delphi component palette (Win32 page) onto your form (or in a data module used by the form). Double-click that new `TImageList`, click the `Add` button on the `ImageList Editor` that appears, and add images. Close the `ImageList Editor'.

Go back to your form. Click on the `RzGroup2` item, and drop down the list in the Object Inspector for the `SmallImages` property, and choose the imagelist you added in the first step.

Set the `ImageIndex` of the `Print` item to the appropriate index in the `ImageList` you assigned to the `RzGroup` in the previous step.